# PyDAQmx importing confusion

Tags: python, python-import, nidaqmx

I'm trying to use PyDAQmx. If I try to import like

```
    from PyDAQmx.DAQmxFunctions import *
    ...
    DAQmxResetDevice(ch) #unresolved
```

the function call is not recognized. However the following works just fine:

```
    import PyDAQmx.DAQmxFunctions as daq
    ...
    daq.DAQmxResetDevice(ch) #fine
```

Any idea why that might be? I'd like to use the first case just to avoid unnecessary clutter in my code since there will be a lot of function calls from that library. I know importing has been discussed to death and I looked at quite a few threads, but couldn't really find anything explaining my issue.

FYI, python 2.7, PyCharm 4.5.3 Community Edition, NI-DAQ 14.5.1, PyDAQmx 1.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyDAQmx doesn't have an `__all__` definition in its `__init__.py`: 
https://github.com/clade/PyDAQmx/blob/master/PyDAQmx/__init__.py

Without an `__all__`, Python doesn't know what to [import](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package).